# Webpack - any sort of async call stops all the js

Tags: asynchronous, webpack

I'm running webpack and this is all the js I have in my app.js file:

```
import '../styles/index.scss';
console.log('test');
```

The console.log is working in the browser. If now I add any sort of asynchronous call (I tried fetch() and axios) the console is no longer working in the browser and I have NO idea why.

```
import '../styles/index.scss';
import axios from 'axios';

console.log('test');

axios.get('http://webcode.me').then(resp => {
    console.log(resp.data);
});
```

Comment: [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)  I have checked what you gave here on my webpack boilerplate and everything works as it should.

Comment: Thanks @GrzegorzT. You were right, I tried to create a reproducible example at it was working for me as well. Turns out the issue was that I'm working with django and webpack was splitting up files in a bundle, which django had troubles importing separedly, luckily there's python package for that and it fixed the issue.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone getting here using Django, you need to use django-webpack-loader to import the generated bundle: https://github.com/django-webpack/django-webpack-loader